# When shall I get possibility to up-vote a comment?

Tags: support, comments

There are comments under questions/answers, each can have none or more votes (I can see them). I can't vote for a comment. I guess, one should have an achievement  in order to get the possibility. What are the achievements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You need 15 reputation to upvote comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/252301)

<sub>Bla-bla-bla *— added this just to have possibility to post my answer. Because too short texts are automatically converted to comments. But I want this question to have an answer to not look as unanswered.*</sub>